# hazelcast-hibernate:caching is not happening

Tags: java, hibernate, caching, hazelcast

I am running sample application configurating the hibernate second level cache to hazelcast.
For testing, I am running the Junit 2 times, in the first run, the DB query is getting called, that DB query is not getting ached in the second run Junit.

```
<prop key="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache">true</prop>
<prop key="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache">true</prop>
<prop key="hibernate.cache.use_minimal_puts">true</prop>
<prop key="hibernate.cache.hazelcast.use_lite_member">true</prop>
<prop key="hibernate.cache.region.factory_class">com.hazelcast.hibernate.HazelcastCacheRegionFactory</prop>
```

Could any body let us know, do we need to any configuration in this regard.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the session factory doesn't get discarded between two consecutive unit test runs?

It really depends on your unit tests configurations but the theory says you should run each test in isolation, because they are not guaranteed to be run in any specific order.

You can test the 2nd level cache in the same unit test, you need to make sure the test is not @Transactional and you can a @Transactional service/dao twice.

In the first Transaction it should hit the database and it will be loaded in the 1st and 2nd level level cache.

In the second one, you have a new Session but the entity should be available in the 2nd level level cache.

Comment: I am running the Junits parallelly to check the distributed cache using  hazelcast.I am explicity synchronizing between them.